# Solutions to multivariate equation

Tags: equation-solving, variable

Is there any way to get Mathematica to give a set of solutions (pairs of x and y that are integers) to an equation with multiple variables? Something like:

```
x^3*y+4x*y^3+x^2-4xy+4y^2 = 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FindInstance[x^3*y + 4 x*y^3 + x^2 - 4 x*y + 4 y^2 == 4, {x, y}, Integers, 10]

(*{{x -> -1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> 1}, 
   {x -> -2, y -> 0}, {x -> 2, y -> 0}}
*)
```

Comment: awesome! thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
Solve[x^3*y + 4 x*y^3 + x^2 - 4 x*y + 4 y^2 == 4, {x, y}, Integers]
(*
  {{x -> -2, y -> 0}, {x -> -1, y -> 1}, {x -> 0, y -> -1},
   {x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> -1}, {x -> 2, y -> 0}}
*)
```

Comment: oh, i didn't realize that all i needed to do was to add "Integers" >.< ... good to know! thanks!

Comment: @Solarmew You're welcome.